# How to add attendee with modify permission in google calendar api

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm working with google calendar api and I've faced an issue: I want to create an event on google calendar and add **invitees** with **modify permission** but default permission is read-only?

So can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried checking the documentation.   What have you tried so far?  We need to see your code to be able to help you with issues.

Comment: The Property you're looking is **guestsCanModify** it is mentioned in the [Event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) properties table, but it's not documented :/  but it seems you can get and set it, [api-library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Calendar_1_1v3_1_1Data_1_1Event.html#a06a86a8f9cd5ed273543e55c300c3eec)

Comment: Yes I found that property and it worked